# How to display the html text correctly inside php?

Tags: php, html

Im a beginner on php and html so please me i currently working on log in system and i want to correctly echo the html inside the php tag, my code error shows unexpected T_STRING, show me the correct way sir

```
    <?php
              if(Convert.ToString(Session['roleid']) == '1'){
              echo '<p>';
              echo '<a href='add_account.php' class='btn btn-success'>'Add Account'</a>';
              echo '</p>';
              }else{

          }
            ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace 
`'<a href='add_account.php' class='btn btn-success'>'Add Account'</a>'` with 
`'<a href="add_account.php" class="btn btn-success">Add Account</a>'`. you got the error because you tried to use single quotes inside a string you started with single quotes

Comment: sir can i ask a question why my if else isnt working i use print_r($_SESSION) to make sure the value store but when i run the code its not working its not showing the html even though the role_id is 1

Comment: @KenVerganio try replacing your if statement with `if (isset($_SESSION['roleid']) && $_SESSION['roleid'] = 1) { //condition }else { //condition }`

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using:

```
echo '<a href="'.add_account.php.'" class=btn btn-success>Add Account</a>';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add variables into html codes, there is 3 ways to do it.

First one is the non practical one; using separate echo commands. Which is not necessary.

Second one, you use that format; echo "bla 'bla' bla ".$your_var."bla bla bla";
Third one is using other quot to do it; echo 'bla "bla" bla'.$your_var.'bla "bla" bla';

If you want to use that quot for you paragraph in HTML it will try to end your paragraph. Also you can use HTML codes for quot like &qout; for that one.

Last also, dont use echo for calling php file. Use include_once command to do it.